# JWrapper application not running correctly

Tags: jwrapper

I am using the beta application for JWrapper to create the XML file.

Following this page there are no errors:
http://www.jwrapper.com/getting-started.html

The program is bundled into application files that can be run.

But when run it appears they just sit idle. I'm making a simple game, so a window should appear.

There are absolutely no errors running, even when run from the command line. No window appears, but the process appears in task manager. I am on windows 8.1

I've run out of ideas

Any help is really appreciated

I have a feeling I am not creating the xml properly but then I imagine I would get errors

Comment: Tried using sampleapp.xml as template, now I am getting javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file! I also get this when trying to jwrap the sample project.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors in the logs, either for your app or for the JW launching apps (GenericUpdater etc)?

http://www.jwrapper.com/guide-where-your-app-is-installed-and-logs.html